# What are these items?

Tags: lighting, fans

I've found a collection of things in the house I just bought and I'm not sure if I need to hold onto them or throw them all away. Can anyone help me identify what these things are and if I need them? Are they expensive?

[image]

Comment: Is that all of them or you have many of each?

Comment: This is all of them. I haven't found any missing lighting trims or fan grates, so I'm guessing these are all extra

Comment: You may decide several years from now that you want to add some recessed lights. If so, and you have these, you'll save some money. I'd put them all in a box, label it "Recessed light stuff and plastic grill" and put it in the attic. If you find it in five years and haven't used it, then I'd trash it.

Answer (score 2):

The object in the bottom is a grate for a fan, probably a bathroom fan.

All the other objects look like trims for light fixtures, perhaps recessed/pot lights.

As far as if you "need" them, I can't answer that.  The might be garbage, they might be spares, or you might have missing trims throughout your house.

Comment: Do these types of things cost much to replace?

Comment: The fan cover, no, but the lighting trims can be expensive.

Comment: The eyeball trims are really expensive, maybe 50-80 USD?? -depending on the manufacturer, also the installation (retainer clips or springs) of some light trims are brand specific, if they are a more than a few years old.

Comment: The upper left looks like a 6" trim *eyeball* style. The others look like 4" trims (although several look like they are oversized to cover 6" holes from older units.